# How do I multiply a HTML value on a page by a percentage (15%)

Tags: javascript, multiplication, tax

I am new to JavaScript and would appreciate some guidance, I am trying to take a HTML value from page without Tax and update that same value to be inclusive of Tax.

Tax in my country is calculated at 15% of the value hence the 1.15

**Javascript**

```
var x = document.querySelector('.product-detail-exc-vat');
var y = 1.15;
var z = x * y;
x.querySelector('.product-detail-exc-vat').innerHTML=z;
```

**HTML**

```html
<span class="product-detail-exc-vat">100</span>
```

My expected result is 115 within the HTML, where am I going wrong?

Comment: `x` is an `HTMLElement` you need to get its `value` or `textContent` depending on its type

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.querySelector('.product-detail-exc-vat').innerText;
var y = 1.15;
var z = x * y;
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = z;
document.querySelector('.result2').innerHTML = z.toFixed(2);
```

```html
value: <span class="product-detail-exc-vat">100</span><br />
value + tax: <span class="result"></span><br />
rounded value + tax (2 decimal places): <span class="result2"></span>
```